# Introduced us to humanity Vs Introduced Humanity to us

Tags: grammaticality

> We were introduced to the concept of humanity by Ron.

Vs

> The concept of humanity was introduced to us by Ron.

What's the difference? Introduce us to humanity vs introduce humanity to us? Which one of the above sentences is more common, and why?

Comment: I think you mean “which of those **constructs** is more common” – I don’t think either one of those is a very “common” sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these sentences are grammatically correct. If a native English speaker were to use either of these two constructions, they would be more likely to use the first than the second. However, in conveying the message intended by these two sentences,  a native English speaker would be much more likely to say:

> Ron introduced us to the concept of humanity.

If you asked most English speakers why they chose one construct over the other, they probably could not give a specific reason other than, "It sounds better that way."

Comment: You’re right when you say that many native speakers might have trouble articulating _why_ one option sounds better than another. But [this column](http://deathbypassivevoice.com/all/passive/) explains it pretty well, and raises an excellent point: I think the first one could be salvaged if we said, “Thanks to Ron, we were introduced to the concept of humanity."

Comment: @J.R. I agree completely. I chose not to discuss the concept of passive voice as I felt that you had already covered sufficiently in your response.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you’re aiming to be a dreadful writer, the answer to your question is **neither**.

Most would say:

> Ron introduced us to the concept of humanity.

Remember, the house may be cleaned by Sarah, but [**Sarah cleans the house once a week**](https://www.opencolleges.edu.au/careers/blog/what-passive-voice-and-why-should-you-avoid-it) – whether it needs it or not.

(Note: the link is to a column called *What is Passive Voice and Why Should You Avoid It?* and the example is taken from the beginning of that column.)